# Visual Studio wants to compile a directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors, cmake

I am generating a visual studio 2010 project using CMake 2.8.5.

While compiling, I regularly get the following error:

```
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:/Users/barbier/projects/MorphoGraphX/src/': Permission denied
```

I checked everywhere in the user interface, and it doesn't seem that this directory is in the list of files to be compiled. I also read in other places it could be due to an empty folder in the additional include directories, but it is not the case for me.

This bug is extremely annoying, as it happens most times, but not 100% of the time, and I really, really don't know why it happens.

Any suggestion welcome.

**Update**

Ok, I found the problem: I hadn't seen a single line, left by some other coder on my project, adding `-I C:/Users/barbier/projects/MorphoGraphX/src/` to the command line, only for certain files. However, does anybody knows why the problem happened only sometimes? Also, this `-I` doesn't appear in the command line anywhere in the user interface. It didn't even appear on the final command line created by VC++ ...

Comment: can you provide the cmake file?

Comment: Let me try to reduce it first.

Answer (score 0):

Open the project file in a text editor. It should be in XML so a smart text editor will work best. I don't think that you can convince Visual Studio to edit it as text or XML though, so use some other tool.

Then look for the problem directory. You can edit the XML directly but it isn't always a good idea. Looking for the directory might give you an idea for where to look for it in Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason (probably because the project was large), I couldn't find anything relevant to the problem. Anyway, I fixed this, but I still think there is a problem in the manner information is presented and processed.